# How generically extract comments from different websites?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to extract comments from [Dawn.com](http://www.dawn.com/news/1267272/democracys-woes) as well as from Tribune.com from any article.  The way I'm extracting comments is, to target the class  `<div class="comment__body  cf">` on Dawn while class="content" on Tribune.com

How can I do it generically? It means,  There is no similar pattern on these websites through which this can be achieve by one class.

**Shall I write separate code for each website?**

Comment: One class that represents the comment in your format, but the method to retrieve them has to be different depending on website. I don't understand what is the problem here?

Comment: It means there is no generic way to access comments from all websites using one code (Using same class name for all websites in other words generic way)? We have to give it different class names in different websites.

Comment: You will have to live with different websites having different underlying structures. The interface for how you handle the comments should be generic though. Maybe you could read up on dependency injection. You pass the website specific parsing code to your class that handles whatever you want to do with your comments.

Comment: @user3387223 . That made me clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301865/how-to-generically-crawl-different-websites-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All web sites use different `html` to represent the views and their comments. 
You have to implement different crawlers for each site. You may also create a library file to keep there generic functions and not repeat some trivial functions.